# Windows: Switch between Display Settings (3 or more Displays)

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line, settings, monitor

How can i switch (respectively save and restore) between display settings.
All ways i found works only with two displays. But i have four connected.
Is there a way to chang it with comandline tools e.g. PowerShell.

For example,
in one configuration I want to stretch the desktop over three screens, the fourth duplicates the first screen or is disabled.

Or the desktop is only cloned on two and the others are disabled.

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on  http://superuser.com or another StackExchange site. Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. ***Please*** read  https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic , https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. GoodLuck

Answer (score 0):

[NirSoft MultiMonitorTool](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/multi_monitor_tool.html) has command line support for a variety of monitor related functions...

eg. Disable Monitor 1 and Enable Monitor 3:

```
MultiMonitorTool.exe /disable 1
MultiMonitorTool.exe /enable 3
```

You can also save and load specific configurations:

```
MultiMonitorTool.exe /SaveConfig "c:\temp\monitors1.cfg"
MultiMonitorTool.exe /LoadConfig "c:\temp\monitors1.cfg"
```

Comment: I try MultiMonitorTool.exe. I can Enable/disable Displays, change Resolution and Position. But i can not switch between Clone-Mode and Extend-Mode.